# Here Maps API ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment UNKNOWN

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to use Here Maps Sdk with the Premium trial. I've followed this tutorial : 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html

But when running the app I have an error: `Fragment UNKNOWN` and a blank map fragment.
Of course I've checked the package name, app id, app code and License key inside the AndroidManifest.

I've built the BasicMapSolution SDK sample project, replacing app id etc., and BasicMapSolution works just fine. I can't find what's wrong in my project.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fr.alan.myapp">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
        android:value="App id from Here website"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
        android:value="App code from Here website "/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
        android:value="License key"/>

    <service
        android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
        android:label="MyAppMapService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="fr.alan.myapp.MapService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.alan.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
package fr.alan.myapp

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    // permissions request code
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    /**
     * Permissions that need to be explicitly requested from end user.
     */
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };

    // map embedded in the map fragment
    private Map map = null;

    // map fragment embedded in this activity
    private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermissions();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);

        // Set up disk cache path for the map service for this application
        boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
                getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
                "com.here.android.tutorial.MapService");

        if (!success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to set isolated disk cache path.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                        // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();
                        // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                        map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                                Map.Animation.NONE);
                        // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                        map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Error", "ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment " + error);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the dynamically controlled permissions and requests missing permissions from end user.
     */
    protected void checkPermissions() {
        final List<String> missingPermissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        // check all required dynamic permissions
        for (final String permission : REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS) {
            final int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                missingPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            // request all missing permissions
            final String[] permissions = missingPermissions
                    .toArray(new String[missingPermissions.size()]);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            final int[] grantResults = new int[REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS.length];
            Arrays.fill(grantResults, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            onRequestPermissionsResult(REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS, REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS,
                    grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                for (int index = permissions.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
                    if (grantResults[index] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // exit the app if one permission is not granted
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Required permission '" + permissions[index]
                                + "' not granted, exiting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // all permissions were granted
                initialize();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_map.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        tools:context=".BasicMapActivity" />

    <!-- Map Fragment embedded with the map object -->
    <fragment
        class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the bug by myself.

when i call

```
boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
            getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
            "fr.alan.myapp.MapService");
```

`"fr.alan.myapp.MapService"` : that's the intent name of the map service.

Must match in AndroidManifest :

```
<service
        android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"
        android:label="MyAppMapService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="fr.alan.myapp.MapService">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>`
```